# Crafting missing components

Tags: the-witcher-3

I have a fair few crafting item (potions, decotions, bombs, and items) that have some missing components. I know that smiths can break down some components into others.

For example, to craft a sword I need three `monster eyes` which I do not have.  I do have seven `Nekker eyes` which a smith can break down into seven (or as many as I like) `monster eyes`.

What I want to know is if there is a way to find out if I can get the missing components I need from the components I have?  I could write all the ones I need, then trawl through the list of breaking component down but that seem a little tedious.

Am I missing something?

Comment: So, why the down vote(s)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no such function which could do that. The only choice you have is to manually check every of your items if they can be converted into the material you need. There are some patterns though, for example almost any specific wooden item can be converted to wood, and any monster skull can be converted into an usual skull. But in general, you have to do all the work by yourself.

Comment: In my opinion, learning these little patterns ("Oh! Monster eyes are something I can get from Nekker eyes, that makes sense!") is part of the fun of the game, and subtly reinforces the underlying "lore" of the game in an enjoyable way.